# Custom NSView draws over controls on top of it

Tags: objective-c, macos, drawing, nsview

I have an `NSView` with a custom subclass that draws a grid of rounded rectangles inside it. This `NSView` was placed with interface builder and on top of it I have some `NSButton`s.

The problem is that sometimes when the view is re-drawn (ie, when i click a button on top of it) then it re-draws over some of the buttons that are meant to stay on top. When this happens only the smaller rounded rects appear over the buttons though, not the background one that is drawn before the loop.

Here is the code form drawRect:

```
[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];

NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
[[NSColor grayColor] set];
[path fill];

[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

for( int r = 0; r < 15; r++ ){
    for( int c = 0; c < 15; c++ ) {

        [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];

        // Draw shape
        NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(20 * c, 20 * r, 15, 15);
        NSBezierPath *roundedRect = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: rect xRadius:1 yRadius:1];

        [roundedRect setClip];

        // Fill
        [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedHue:0 saturation:0 brightness:0.3 alpha:1] set];
        [roundedRect fill];


        // Stroke
        [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedHue:0 saturation:0 brightness:0.5 alpha:1] set];
        [roundedRect setLineWidth:2.0];
        [roundedRect stroke];

        [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

**Update:** Simplified the code, added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

the mac has issues with overlapping sibling views. it didn't work before.... 10.6 and it still doesnt work quite often.

use a proper superview / subview hierachy

Comment: what would the proper hierarchy be in this case?

Answer (score 0):

OK I just managed to solve this by removing the `setClip` and finding a different way to draw the inner stroke.

I'm sure it's possible to solve this while still using `setClip` but this solution worked fine for me this time.